# Composite Template Response Gives Invalid Request Error while creating the envelope

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

I have tried to create a template for composite template, while getting the response from docusign I am facing some issues. Below is the XML which I am creating for composite template.

I am getting a BAD Request Error.

```
 <envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
      <accountId>ACCOUNTID</accountId>
      <status>sent</status>
      <compositeTemplates>
        <compositeTemplate>
          <serverTemplates>
            <serverTemplate>
              <sequence>1</sequence>
              <templateId>xxxxxxxxxxxx</templateId>
            </serverTemplate>
          </serverTemplates>
          <inlineTemplates>
            <inlineTemplate>
              <sequence>1</sequence>
              <recipients>
                <signers>
                  <signer>
                    <email>xxxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com</email>
                    <name>234 234</name>
                    <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                    <roleName>Contractor</roleName>
                    <clientUserId>1</clientUserId>
                  </signer>
                </signers>
              </recipients>
            </inlineTemplate>
          </inlineTemplates>
        </compositeTemplate>
        <compositeTemplate>
          <serverTemplates>
            <serverTemplate>
              <sequence>2</sequence>
              <templateId>xxxxxxxxxxxx</templateId>
            </serverTemplate>
          </serverTemplates>
          <inlineTemplates>
            <inlineTemplate>
              <sequence>1</sequence>
              <recipients>
                <signers>
                  <signer>
                    <email>xxxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com</email>
                    <name>234 234</name>
                    <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                    <roleName>Contractor</roleName>
                    <clientUserId>1</clientUserId>
                  </signer>
                </signers>
              </recipients>
            </inlineTemplate>
          </inlineTemplates>
        </compositeTemplate>
        <compositeTemplate>
          <serverTemplates>
            <serverTemplate>
              <sequence>3</sequence>
              <templateId>xxxxxxxxxxxx</templateId>
            </serverTemplate>
          </serverTemplates>
          <inlineTemplates>
            <inlineTemplate>
              <sequence>1</sequence>
              <recipients>
                <signers>
                  <signer>
                    <email>xxxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com</email>
                    <name>234 234</name>
                    <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                    <roleName>Contractor</roleName>
                    <clientUserId>1</clientUserId>
                  </signer>
                </signers>
              </recipients>
            </inlineTemplate>
          </inlineTemplates>
        </compositeTemplate>
        <compositeTemplate>
          <serverTemplates>
            <serverTemplate>
              <sequence>4</sequence>
              <templateId>xxxxxxxxxxxx</templateId>
            </serverTemplate>
          </serverTemplates>
          <inlineTemplates>
            <inlineTemplate>
              <sequence>1</sequence>
              <recipients>
                <signers>
                  <signer>
                    <email>xxxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com</email>
                    <name>234 234</name>
                    <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                    <roleName>Contractor</roleName>
                    <clientUserId>1</clientUserId>
                  </signer>
                  <signer>
                    <email />
                    <name />
                    <recipientId>4</recipientId>
                    <roleName>Legal</roleName>
                    <clientUserId>1</clientUserId>
                  </signer>
                </signers>
              </recipients>
            </inlineTemplate>
          </inlineTemplates>
        </compositeTemplate>
        <compositeTemplate>
          <serverTemplates>
            <serverTemplate>
              <sequence>5</sequence>
              <templateId>xxxxxxxxxxxx</templateId>
            </serverTemplate>
          </serverTemplates>
          <inlineTemplates>
            <inlineTemplate>
              <sequence>1</sequence>
              <recipients>
                <signers>
                  <signer>
                    <email>xxxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com</email>
                    <name>234 234</name>
                    <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                    <roleName>Contractor</roleName>
                    <clientUserId>1</clientUserId>
                  </signer>
                </signers>
              </recipients>
            </inlineTemplate>
          </inlineTemplates>
        </compositeTemplate>
      </compositeTemplates>
    </envelopeDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DocuSign REST API auto-generated help page to figure out which part of your request is invalid.  It shows examples for all the API calls in v2 and you can look at valid requests in JSON or XML format:

https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help